# Lightning console method workspaceAPI.closeTab() is not working after keeping the console tab open for sometime(approx. 2 hrs)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, performance, console, chrome

The following method for closing the console tab is working if user launches the page and trying to Cancel immediately. But if the page is idle for sometime like 2 hours and if user try to Cancel , the console tab is not closing.

```
closeCurrentTab: function(component,event,helper){
   let workspaceAPI;
   let closedTabId;
   workspaceAPI= component.find("workspace");
   workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
         closedTabId = response.tabId;
         workspaceAPI.closeTab({ 
          tabId: closedTabId 
       });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you add a console.log in the catch function to log any issues?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava - This issue is happening in production environment and cannot reproducible in any sandbox.